# Laravel update Query not work Call to a member function fill() on null

Tags: php, laravel

When i update data with changing user id in my drop down value and allocate a specific venue to user it return error and cannot update data.

> Error :Call to a member function fill() on null

Image Added: where client is a users and when i allocate star venue to vinay it returns error

[image]

Here is my model function code  which i try

```
  public static function saveOrUpdate(Request $request) {
    try {

        $checkBoxes = [
            'is_premium',
            'is_verified',
            'is_outside_catering',
            'is_indoor',
            'is_outdoor',
            'has_parking',
            'has_valet'
        ];
        foreach($checkBoxes as $checkbox) {
            if(!$request->has($checkbox)) {
                $request->merge([$checkbox => 0]);
            }
        }

        $venue = false;

        DB::transaction(function () use ($request, &$venue) {
            $id = $request->get('id', false); // gt id here
            $clientId = $request->get('client_id', false); // gt cleint id here
            $client = Client::findOrFail($clientId);
            $venue = $client->venues()->findOrNew($id); // gt venue data
            // added dd($venue) below
            //dd($request->all()); Added array in below

            $venue->fill($request->all());

            try {
                $venue->save();
                $occasions = $request->get('occasions', []);
                $venue->occasions()->sync($occasions);

                if($id) {
                    // Here I am gtng error
                    $venue->venueParameter->fill($request->all())->save();
                } else {
                    $venue->venueParameter()->create($request->all());
                }
            } catch (\Exception $ex) {
                echo $ex->getMessage();
                dd($ex->getTraceAsString());
            }
        });

        return $venue;
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        throw $ex;
    }
}
```

Here is venue model function for parameter

```
    public function venueParameter() {
    //dd("Welcome"); gt here successfully
    return $this->hasOne(VenueParameter::class);
}
```

Here is my venueparameter model

```
<?php

     namespace App;

     use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class VenueParameter extends Model
  {

    protected $fillable = [

    'venue_id',
    'min_capacity',
    'max_capacity',
    'is_outside_catering',
    'price_list_view',
    'price_details_view',
    'area',
    'is_indoor',
    'indoor_area',
    'is_outdoor',
    'outdoor_area',
    'has_parking',
    'no_of_parkings',
    'has_valet',
    'no_of_rooms',
    'decorator',
];


public $timestamps = false;

const DECORATOR = [
    'Inside' => 'Inside',
    'Outside' => 'Outside',
    'Both' => 'Both'
];

public function venue() {

    return $this->belongsTo(Venue::class);
}
 }
```

Here is what i gt when i dd($request->all())

```
                        "_token" => "dJcVc2pP6fGtBD9FUZYFMnKfHf0ArScjy9mLJfcg"
                        "id" => "8"
                        "name" => "test"
                        "client_id" => "2"
                        "logo" => "public/venue-logo/BO7ZuxbZyUZjo7u35WAyx4ReNlBnGxcFIKo77euo.jpeg"
                        "venue_type_id" => "1"
                        "is_premium" => "1"
                        "is_verified" => "1"
                        "tripadvisor_url" => "http://test.com/home"
                        "venue_url" => "http://test.com/home"
                        "status" => "Active"
                        "min_capacity" => "1"
                        "max_capacity" => "1"
                        "price_list_view" => "1"
                        "price_details_view" => ""
                        "area" => "5000"
                        "indoor_area" => "0"
                        "outdoor_area" => "0"
                        "no_of_parkings" => "0"
                        "decorator" => "Inside"
                        "is_outside_catering" => 0
                        "is_indoor" => 0
                        "is_outdoor" => 0
                        "has_parking" => 0
                        "has_valet" => 0
```

Here is what i gt when i dd($venue)

```
  #attributes: array:12 [▼
"id" => 11
"client_id" => 1
"name" => "zuber"
"venue_url" => "http://premiumbanquets.com/home"
"logo" => "public/venue-logo/Rkt8SV5OLz8pMW6sFfJJUhUFmhSI2VCfBLvI6STd.jpeg"
"venue_type_id" => 1
"is_premium" => 1
"is_verified" => 1
"tripadvisor_url" => "http://premiumbanquets.com/home"
"status" => "Active"
"created_at" => "2017-12-04 13:19:25"
"updated_at" => "2017-12-04 13:19:25"
```

]

How can i overcome on this problem?

Comment: My guess is the venue doesn't have a related venueParameter

Comment: Dump venue and inspect the relationships

Comment: I think `findOrNew($id);` is not find any record related to `$id`, First see the result of `$venue`

Comment: also findOrNew($id) data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$venue = $client->venues()->findOrNew($id);
```

This can be an existing record (is in the database, has an 'id', might have relationships as well) or a new instance, no attributes, no 'id', doesn't exist in the database (and therefor couldn't possibly have any existing relationships).  This is **NOT** the `null` part. `findOrNew` does not return a `null`.

The `null` part is potentially here:

```
$venue->venueParameter->fill($request->all())->save();
```

If `$venue` is a new instance it will not have **any** relationships setup. Even if it is an existing record, it may not have that relationship in the database. So trying to set a property on a related model via dynamic property for a relationship isn't going to get very far. This is going to try and resolve the `venueParameter` relationship (load it), which doesn't exist so it returns a `null`, so:

```
null->fill($request->all())->save(); // is what is happening
```

Comment: Well described.Understand what you want to say.What is my next step ? As i am confused.

Comment: you have to check if `$venue->venueParameter` is null or not (does that relationship exist or not),  if it doesn't exist, create it, if it does, update it .. basically what you are trying to do already, you just need to do the extra check on this relationship

Comment: getting null when  dd($venue->venueParameter);

Comment: yes, that is exactly expected as that is what this entire post is all about

Comment: so @lagbox what can i do now ? reference ?

Comment: if its `null` the relationship doesn't exist .. you have to create it ... its what you are already trying to do, you just did it wrong

Comment: so what can i do to create a relationship i have a two tables which i need to update venue_parameters,venues where venue_parameters has a id of venues(venue_id)

Comment: you already have it in your code ... what do you think that `create` call is for?

Comment: **create** when new data added

Comment: the next statement after the error is creating the relationship ..................  did someone else write this?

Answer (score 0):

Becuase you are doing it wrong way here

`$venue = false;`

according to api [doc](https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html) object must be the instance of laravel Model.

so try changing it to the respective model

`$venue = new Venue();`

if your model is `Venue`

Answer (score 0):

This error is self descriptive

> Error :Call to a member function fill() on null here $vanue get null value try to print $vanue data and check it dd($vanue);

```
    DB::transaction(function () use ($request, &$venue) {
    $id = $request->get('id', false); // gt id here
    $clientId = $request->get('client_id', false); // gt cleint id here
    $client = Client::findOrFail($clientId);
    $venue = $client->venues()->findOrNew($id); // gt venue data
    **//dd($request->all()); Added array in below**

    $venue->fill($request->all()); **//here value of  $venue  is null or blank** 

    dd($vanue) // check this whether it contain NULL or not
```

Comment: added venue array in description

Comment: now try to create $vanue object from venue data  #attributes: array:12 
"id" => 11 ...    $vanue =  Vanue::findOrFail(11//value of id from vanue array);